# How to bold selected text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, text-editor

I had made a text editor in python where I am facing some problems. It has a <kbd>bold</kbd> button which enbolds whole text of the text editor, where I want to on apply it to selected text, but I cannot define the functionality properly.

Please help me to select the text and **bold**.

Here is my code:

```
#bold
bold_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\soham\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\TEXT_EDITOR\\ICONS\\icons2\\bold.png')
bold_btn = ttk.Button(tool_bar, image= bold_icon)
bold_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)

def change_bold():
    text_property=tk.font.Font(font=text_editor['font'])    
    if text_property.actual()['weight'] =='normal':
        text_editor.configure(font=(current_font_family, current_font_size, 'bold'))
    if text_property.actual()['weight'] == 'bold':
        text_editor.configure(font=(current_font_family, current_font_size, 'normal'))

bold_btn.configure(command=change_bold)
```

Comment: Is this for the text widget? There are many tutorials, and the methods for applying formatting to ranges of text is documented. Why do you need our help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
def change_bold():
    textwidget.tag_configure("boldtext",font=textwidget.cget("font")+" bold")
    textwidget.tag_add("boldtext","sel.first","sel.last")
```

To make the text normal again you should change the function to this:

```
textwidget.tag_configure("boldtext",font=textwidget.cget("font")+" bold")
def change_bold():
    if "boldtext" in textwidget.tag_names("sel.first"):
        textwidget.tag_remove("boldtext","sel.first","sel.last")
    else:
        textwidget.tag_add("boldtext","sel.first","sel.last")
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked

But what should I do to bold selection normal again?

I tried using this code, but it do not work

Comment: I edited my answer. Now it accomplishes what you want.