# How can I let the tkinter's text component show colorful words use '\033'?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I have making [a program](https://github.com/penghao123456/sharelink).

It needs show some colorful words use this:
`\033[1mabc`

I tryed this command and ***it failed***:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
text=tk.Text(root)
text.insert('end', '\033[1mabc')
```

It shows ***a tofu and `[1mabc`***.
But ***I want get a red `abc`***.
How can I get it?

P.S.
It will do like this:

```py
import socket
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

// connect the port use socket 'socket'

text=tk.Text(root)
text.insert('end', socket.read(1024))
```

And in the port of the computer:

```py
//socket connected front is 'socket'

// when connect
import subprocess
command=subprocess.Popen(socket.read(1024), shell=True, output=subprocess.PIPE, error=subprocess.INPUT)
socket.send(command.output.read(1024))

// stop the 'command' Popen
```

Comment: You can't use ANSI escape codes with pure `tkinter`. Look at something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64085151/11106801) but instead of `font=...`, use `foreground="red"`

Comment: I had edited this.

Comment: The code that you have is very unsafe. Also you will have to make your own ANSI escape codes parser.

Comment: So how can i make it?

Comment: Basically when you encounter `"\033[1m"`, don't write it on the screen, instead tell `tkinter` to start writing in red. To do that, you can use `text_widget.tag_add("red_fg_tag", "insert", "end")`. That will add a tag named `"red_fg_tag"` from the text cursor's position to the end. If you also have `text_widget.tag_config("red_fg_tag", foreground="red")` somewhere in your code, the text will switch colour to red

Answer (score 3):

You can't, not with `tkinter.Text`. `\033[1m` is an [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), specifically the [Select Graphics Rendition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR) sequence, to change how a *terminal* should color the following text.

`tkinter.Text` does not interpret those sequences at all.

Here's an example of a function that supports a semblance of rich text in a tkinter.Text widget using [tags](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#tags):

```
import tkinter as tk


def set_text_with_attributes(text_widget, texts_and_attributes):
    i_start = text_widget.index(tk.INSERT)
    for i, (text, attributes) in enumerate(texts_and_attributes):
        text_widget.insert(tk.END, text)
        i_end = text_widget.index(tk.INSERT)
        tag_name = f'tag{i}'
        text_widget.tag_add(tag_name, i_start, i_end)
        text_widget.tag_config(tag_name, **attributes)
        i_start = i_end


root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)

set_text_with_attributes(text, [
    ("Hello, ", {}),
    ("World!\n", {"foreground": "red"}),
    ("Once upon a time, ", {"foreground": "black"}),
    ("there was a ", {"foreground": "blue"}),
    ("fox", {"background": "orange"}),
    (" who jumped over ", {}),
    ("the ", {"foreground": "green"}),
    ("lazy ", {"background": "yellow"}),
    ("dog", {"foreground": "purple"}),
])

text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This shows

[image]

Comment: @TheLizzard Improved example with something that doesn't require one to count characters by hand :)

Comment: Can you add some comments? I don't understand your code.@AKX

Comment: @phao What in particular don't you understand? It's pretty simple Python, and even if you don't understand all of it immediately, you can just use it...

Comment: And I want it can automatic get the colors, because I think it may need to show words that are color-coded with ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: I think i see it.

Comment: But how can I remove some words and their tag? @AKX

Comment: If you want to actually use ANSI escape sequences, you will need to write your own parser for them.

Answer (score 0):

As for newbie. Just 15 lines try this.

```
import tkinter as tk

def onclick():
   pass

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.insert(tk.INSERT, "It shows a tofu and [1mabc But I want get a red abc. How can I get it")
text.pack()

text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "1.4")
text.tag_add("start", "1.47", "1.51")
#text.tag_config("start", background="yellow", foreground="red")
text.tag_config("start", foreground="red")
root.mainloop()
```

If you want background and foreground. Comment in line13 and comment out line 14.

Output:

[image]

Comment: This example expects OP to count characters by hand, and the "escape sequence" remains in the text.

Answer (score 0):

for intermediate levels. If you want, select any word or multiple words and highlight and then clear it. I added two buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font


class Pad(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self, bg="#eee")
        self.toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        
        self.bold_btn = tk.Button(self.toolbar,
                                          text="Highlight",
                      command=self.highlight_text)
        
        self.bold_btn.pack(side="left")

        self.clear_btn = tk.Button(self.toolbar,
                                           text="Clear",
                       command=self.clear)
        
        self.clear_btn.pack(side="left")

        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.insert("end", "It shows a tofu and [1mabc. But I want get a red abc. How can I get i")
        self.text.focus()
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        
        self.text.tag_configure("start", foreground="red")
        #self.text.tag_configure("start", background="black", foreground="red")

    def highlight_text(self):   
        try:
            self.text.tag_add("start", "sel.first", "sel.last")     
        except tk.TclError:
            pass


    def clear(self):
        self.text.tag_remove("start", "1.0", 'end')


def demo():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Pad(root).pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

Output:

[image]

Btw, if you want background and foreground. Comment out line 29 and comment in line 30.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to be selecting `abc` by hand.

Comment: It is not by you. It it up to @phao.

Comment: @AKX. I am not pressuring you. I attempted to reduce the code lines.

Comment: So how can I modify the words?